# Inline List on multiple lines depending on the screen size

Tags: html, css

I have an inline list and I'd like it to be split into two distinct lines when the screen becomes too small to accommodate the text (I can define media queries to do so because content is always the same size). Any idea how to make such thing happen ?

Here is what I currently have but when resizing it just shrinks on itself:

```css
.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs__item {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left-width: 0;
}
.tabs__item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tabs__item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use the nth-child selector in a media query to get both halves of the list and define their behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope i helped. This code should do the trick.

```css
.tabs, .tabs2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs__item, .tabs__item2 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left-width: 0;
}
.tabs__item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tabs__item2:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .tabs, .tabs2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  clear:both;
}
  .tabs__item:first-child, .tabs__item2:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tabs__item:last-child, .tabs__item2:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item">Hello</li>
</ul>
<ul class="tabs2">
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
  <li class="tabs__item2">Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually I do have one issue with this solution while it's very good. It only works for even number of <li> because if you had one more <li> they don't have the same size anymore :'(

Comment: A solution would be to give each li a specific width and height.